# Unexpected String Error Require Express Not Getting Found in JS App file

Tags: node.js, express, coffeescript

I have a js web app that is written in express, node, socket io and coffeescript. I am trying to get the local server started on my local machine.

I went to the directory that contained the `package.json` file and ran `npm install` to install all the dependencies which included express.

when I run `npm list` I do see `express` there.

When I try to start the app with

`node app.coffee` inside the directory of where the `app.coffee` is located

its given me this error

```
exports, require, module, __filename, __dirname) { express = require 'express'
                                                                     ^^^^^^^^^
SyntaxError: Unexpected string
    at Module._compile (module.js:439:25)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:474:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:356:32)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:312:12)
    at Function.Module.runMain (module.js:497:10)
    at startup (node.js:119:16)
    at node.js:901:3
```

I made sure I have node by doing

`which node` and I installed coffee script on my machine with

`sudo npm install -g coffee-script`

I even tried

`coffee app.coffee`

I am not sure what else I need to check. The `app.coffee` is in my nodejs folder.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Simply run

```
coffee app.coffee -n
```

You can find out more info [here](http://coffeescript.org/#usage)